# I can't get [class.is-invalid] to work in Angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm trying to make the inputs of a form to get the border red when I click on them and then click outside without writing anything but it's not working and I don't understand why. Can you help me understand why? Thanks.

This is my HTML code:

```
<form [formGroup]="forma" *ngIf="forma" (submit)="submit()">
    <input type="text" formControlName="nombre" [class.is-invalid]="nombreNoValido">
    <input type="text" formControlName="apellido">
    <input type="email" formControlName="email">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    
</form>
```

This is the .ts component:

```
  forma:FormGroup;

  constructor(private infoService: InfoService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { 
    this.initializeForm()
  }
    
  initializeForm(){
    this.forma = this.fb.group({
      nombre: ['', Validators.required],
      apellido: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

  get nombreNoValido(){
    return this.forma.get('nombre').invalid && this.forma.get('nombre').touched
  }
```

Comment: Hello. Did you have any issues seeing the form in the DOM at all? Also, can you show the snippet of the CSS with the class `.is-invalid` that is providing the border? I reproduced the problem in a stackblitz and it worked fine.

Comment: ohmygosh I had misspelled the class in the CSS. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you missed to add in form-control class.when you added means,it will working

<input type="text" **class="form-control"** formControlName="nombre" [class.is-invalid]="nombreNoValido">